# Django `object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()`

Tags: python, django

I have a following code in django:

```
def index(request):
    template_name = 'desks.html'

   # query = Desk.objects.all()

    desk_list = Desk.objects.all

    paginator = Paginator(desk_list, 5)
    page = paginator.page(1)

    return render_to_response(template_name, {'desk_list': page}, )
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:
`object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()`

At my model, I have defined only attributes.

Any idea what a mistake it can be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to call `all`:

```
desk_list = Desk.objects.all()
```

Comment: The same is true if you are using an empty queryset. 
desk_list = Desk.objects.none()

Comment: @sww314: The underlying difference is that `function` and `function()` are completely different things. `x = function; x()` is the same as calling `function()` because `function` refers to the function itself.